# How to specify INITRANS for a partitioned LOB index?

Tags: oracle, indexing, blob, deadlock, oracle11gr2

I have a partitioned table with a BLOB column. When multiple rows per transaction is deleted from this table by multiple users, we often run into ORA-00060 deadlock-s, which, according the trc files, are caused by ITL deadlocks in the *LOB* index partitions. So I want to recreate the table with higher LOB index INITRANS than the default 2. I can do that for a non-partitioned table with `create table ... ( ... lob (...) store as ... ( ... index ... (... initrans 10 ... ) ) )`, but for the partitioned table Oracle says 
"ORA-22879: cannot use the LOB INDEX clause for partitioned tables". Is there any other way I can set INITRANS for a partitioned LOB index?

(Update: Note that I don't need to ALTER the existing table, I can recreate it from scratch. That's usually easier.)

**jonearles's edit follows:**

Here's an example of how the normal method does not work:

```
create table test1(a number, b clob)
partition by range (a) (partition p1 values less than (1));

select * from dba_indexes where owner = user and table_name = 'TEST1';

--ORA-22864: cannot ALTER or DROP LOB indexes
alter index SYS_IL0000111806C00002$$ initrans 3;
```

It's interesting to note that the index DDL looks really odd.  The code below would not run - there's no expression in the index and the parenthesis is not even closed.

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('INDEX', 'SYS_IL0000111806C00002$$') from dual;

  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "JHELLER"."SYS_IL0000111806C00002$$" ON "JHELLER"."TEST1" (
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT) LOCAL
 (PARTITION "SYS_IL_P19289" 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 LOGGING 
  STORAGE( INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" , 
 PARTITION "SYS_IL_P19290" 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 LOGGING 
  STORAGE( INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ) 
  PARALLEL (DEGREE 0 INSTANCES 0)
```

Comment: Might get better response on http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

Oracle technical support said that I can't specify the INITRANS for a partitioned LOB index. However, they have also noticed that using `SECUREFILE` option together with `DEDUPLICATE LOB` option (which we did) might be the cause the problem. So I have given up the `DEDUPLICATE LOB` (just to be sure, replaced it with `KEEP_DUPLICATES`) and now the LOB index deadlocks are gone! (I have written a little stress test, and with that you can cause dozens of dead lock errors in minutes with `DEDUPLICATE LOB`, but none with `KEEP_DUPLICATES`.)

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the reasoning behind the error is that the LOB is also partitioned, so you'd need to alter each partition separately.  I found a note from Oracle that they way to move a LOB partition is:

```
alter table <table name> move partition <table partition name>
lob (<lob column name>) store as (tablespace <lob tablespace name>)
```

So I wonder if you can also use this to change its storage parameters, e.g.:

```
alter table <table name> move partition <table partition name>
lob (<lob column name>) store as (... index ... (... initrans 10 ... ) ) )
```

I don't have partitioning enabled so can't try it out.

Comment: I will try this when I get back to work (next week). However, this table is also "interval partitioned", so the new partitions are created automatically by Oracle.

Comment: A method like this won't normally work here, see the example added to the question.

Comment: @jonearles Sorry, but I don't see the connection between the example you added to the question (which uses ALTER INDEX) and the suggestion in my answer.  You may be right that it won't work; I have no way to test it; but your example doesn't show that as far as I can tell.